# If he wanted to, he would x (Logical Fallacy?)

Tags: fallacies

Not sure if this is the correct stack site to post, but is this a fallacy & if so, which one?

Curious about this as this has been a trending saying lately.

If he wanted to, he would x (Logical Fallacy?)

x being things like “If he wanted to text you, he would.” Or, “If he wanted to see you, he would.”

Comment: No "logical" at all.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA ?

Comment: "A [logical fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy#Formal_fallacy) or *non sequitur* (Latin for "it does not follow") is a flaw in the structure of a deductive argument which renders the argument invalid. " Where is the "deductive argument" here?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA

ah yea ok-- it

This is phrase is usually used in dating--

if he wanted to he (would) ... do x

x being things like

“If he wanted to text you, he would.”

Or, “If he wanted to see you, he would.”

Comment: @guest It is a conditional, so it is indeed logical. We also all understand this sort of statements intuitively. The speaker is just asserting the conditional, so he or she wouldn't commit any logical fallacy. You may disagree with the statement, but it is not a reasoning or an argument. We usually use this sort of statement to tell someone what they may not want to hear, so this may explain your feeling that there is something unpleasant in the statement. But it is not a logical fallacy.

Comment: @Speakpigeon is this not begging the question because it's literally begging the second side of portion.

or appeal to pity / emotion or false dilemma? because it can use manipulation of listner?

Comment: I call it an **oversimplification**. There are many reasons why people don't do things that they want to. Someone can't text you if their phone died. The point of the statement seems to be to *infer* something about intent from visible conditions. But as I have said to people many times, "a *lack* of communication is not a *message*." Imputing motives usually goes wrong. Just ask them.

Comment: @guest "*begging the question*" Only arguments can beg the question. Your conditional is not an argument. It's a statement, like: *This is so and so*. You may disagree that it is so and so, but that doesn't make it an argument. - 2. "*appeal to pity / emotion or false dilemma*" Uh? There is no appeal to emotion or pity. There is no dilemma either. 3. "*manipulation*" Any statement whatever can be used to manipulate the listener.

Answer (score 4):

There are premises, which could be correct or incorrect. And there are logic rules that allow us to deduce results from the premises. Your example would more likely be:

1. If he wanted to text you, he would.
2. He didn’t text you.
3. Therefore, he didn’t want to text you.

The logic here is perfectly fine. If both premises were true, then the conclusion would be true.

Premise 2 might be false because you missed a text message. But premise 1 is very wrong. He might want to text you, but might not have a phone, might have an empty battery, might have lost your phone number. So the premise 1 may very well be wrong.

(I see it as a premise and not as a logic rule, because it is much too specialised).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest this is an **appeal to probability** -- the logical fallacy of taking something for granted because it would probably be the case (or might possibly be the case).

An example that Wikipedia gives is: If I do not bring my umbrella (premise), it will rain. (invalid conclusion)

In this case, it seems possible, even probable, that if he wanted to text you, he would, but obviously there's any number of reasons why he might not, and hence this is an appeal to probability.